# Benchmarking for Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, exchange, sql, benchmarking

Does somebody know products to benchmark new hardware for servers 2008 R2 ?

The goal is to validate server for future purpose like Exchange,SQL, ... 
and secondly perform a stress test to assure it is consistent.

Comment: Perfmon.  It's free.

Comment: While Perfmon is a great tool, it doesn't do any benchmarking for you. It merely monitors whatever you are doing. I would like to see some tips for free software/suites that does I/O and CPU benchmarking, and outputs a result that can be used in comparison with other systems.